# Function mcrypt_*() is deprecated

Tags: php, mysql, iis, phpmyadmin, windows-server-2012-r2

I just finished installing phpMyAdmin, and every time I open the page, I'm getting overflowed with these messages:

> Deprecation Notice in .\libraries\phpseclib\Crypt\Base.php#1592
>   Function mcrypt_list_algorithms() is deprecated
>
> Backtrace
>
> .\libraries\phpseclib\Crypt\Rijndael.php#269:
>   phpseclib\Crypt\Base->isValidEngine(integer 2)
>   .\libraries\phpseclib\Crypt\Base.php#1659:
>   phpseclib\Crypt\Rijndael->isValidEngine(integer 2)
>   .\libraries\phpseclib\Crypt\AES.php#128:
>   phpseclib\Crypt\Base->_setEngine()
>   .\libraries\plugins\auth\AuthenticationCookie.php#772:
>   phpseclib\Crypt\AES->setKey(string 'kvIZO)34!;Qdh,)+')
>   .\libraries\plugins\auth\AuthenticationCookie.php#345:
>   PMA\libraries\plugins\auth\AuthenticationCookie->cookieDecrypt( string
>   '{"iv":"(redacted)","mac":"(redacted)","payload":"(redacted)"}',
>   string '(redacted)', )
>   .\libraries\common.inc.php#758:
>   PMA\libraries\plugins\auth\AuthenticationCookie->authCheck()
>   .\server_sql.php#14: require_once(.\libraries\common.inc.php)

Each one is different in terms of mentioned function, although they all start with "mcrypt_". Trying to "ignore all" messages makes them disappear once, but they appear once again after I refresh the page.

I've also tried adding the following line to the php.ini file and restarting the web server, but that didn't cease those messages: **error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED & ~E_DEPRECATED**

phpMyAdmin 4.6.5.2, mySQL 5.5.45, PHP 7.1, IIS Web Server 8.5, all running under Windows Server 2012 R2. Ideas?

Comment: Huh. I tried to search for it and I didn't find it, I guess I need to step up my keyword game... Thank you, Alex's workaround worked.

Comment: You are welcome :) please mark the dup as correct so this question will be closed